# Run config script on next/first boot?

Tags: linux, configuration, chef

I'm wearing the devops hat for my company. All our infrastructure is manually configured in AWS and I would like to start using Chef for configuration.

First step: Make it easy to bootstrap an environment and reach out to the chef server! Here is my thoughts on how to approach it.

1. Start a fresh Ubuntu AMI
2. Add a script that runs at startup the bootstraps an enviro (ruby, ruby gems, etc.) and registers with Chef.
3. Squirrel away this as a custom AMI so I can start many of these.

So, my question is: What is the best way to go about running a script *just once* on the next startup?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the Opscode wiki entry on using Chef with EC2?

http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/EC2+Bootstrap+Fast+Start+Guide

Basically, you would start up an EC2 instance you can ssh into, then run a knife bootstrap command against it.  The knife command will do all that stuff you have in Step 2.  You can tweak the knife bootstrap template to specify the Chef recipes/roles you want to apply to the node.  You should not need to do Step 3.

Answer (score 2):

Do read the OpsCode wiki. In my opinion, it has too much information for someone to easily lose track.

Your approach should be like this:

> Use Knife to launch the fresh Ubuntu/CentOS AMI with the required run list.
>   Your run list is basically roles which contain the cookbooks. Cookbooks contain recipes of what you actually want to automate.

Ideally, you should never create a custom AMI from this chef managed image. Thats the whole point of using these configuration management tools.